# Partial screenshot with chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I'm trying to build my first ever Chrome extension, and want it to take screenshots. I know Chrome has a captureVisibleTab API to get the visible area of the screen. I have gotten that to work. But, I want to be able to take partial screenshots (eg. user clicks and drags the mouse on the screen to select a certain rectangular area of content). How would this work on Chrome? I don't see an API for this, but I know Awesome Screenshot and some other screenshot extensions do this.

I am using `.mouseup` and `.mousedown` to detect mouse clicks and `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` to get coordinates on the page. But, how do I get a rectangle to show up on the page? I have to convert the webpage to a canvas, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. Also, once I get the selected area, how do I convert that to an image and get the dataURI like the return value that the chrome API gives?

Should I be doing this some other way instead? Thanks for your help!

Comment: there are existing s.o. questions that show how to convert to canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest first generating the overall screenshot ([example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:screenshot) for others), then cropping it later based off of the user data you collected. You can crop the image using JavaScript and the HTML5 `<canvas>` element. ([example code](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/))

As for converting the webpage to a `<canvas>` element, take an initial screenshot, display it on the canvas using the [`drawImage()`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp) function.

Then, you could use either the method shown in the "[example code](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/)", or a library such as [cropper](http://dev.vizuina.com/cropper/) to draw the rectangle on screen for the UI.

The [example code](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/) can also show you how to turn the selected area into a dataURI.

Comment: As a general note, it's bad to only link to example code. You have lots of examples here, so copying everything over is impractical / potentially copyright-questionable, but at least add a phrase or two describing the method for each example.

Comment: @fond42518 thanks for your help and the detailed examples! I understand how to resize from the link you provided. But, I am still not sure how to get the rectangle with the start and end coordinates to show up on the original webpage. I would like it to be something similar to the UI of the other screenshot extensions (e.g. Awesome Screenshot). How can I get the webpage to grey out and display the grid-looking pointer and rectangular selection on the page itself? That's what I meant by converting the webpage to a canvas. I don't want to create a canvas on another tab and then resize.